# Laravel User Management System

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, user-management, laravel-5.4

This feels like a silly question only because I feel like it should be obvious or easy to find, yet I've looked everywhere. Laravel has a beautifully simply way of creating user registration,login,password resets, etc. with a simple `php artisan make:auth` command. It seems like there's got to be a really simple way to setup User and Role management as well. Isn't this just as common a need as Registration and Login? I've looked what seems like everywhere and I've seen posts that elude to it but haven't found anything on how to add it. I really don't want to reinvent this wheel if Laravel has already made it simple. I've played that game enough times already. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

Answer (score 1):

it is easy (many articles and youtube videos on how to do that), but not as simple as making the user management system. there is no artisan command to do it for you. so you gonna have to reinvent that wheel

unless you want to use a third party code.

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust (from @halloei's comment)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what is available in `Spark` and you will see that the guys at laravel have done this, however it is not in there interest to make it that easy in the basic `laravel` framework.

https://spark.laravel.com/

If you are willing to shell out $99 you can get your auth and a bunch of other features.